# Which day of the week is today (Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday or Sunday) if one of the statements is false?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

- Today is neither Sunday nor Wednesday.
- Tomorrow is not Sunday or Wednesday.
- Yesterday was not Friday.
- Monday was not the day before yesterday, neither was Sunday.

Which day of the week is today (Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday or Sunday) if one of the statements is false?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Today is

> Sunday

*Today is neither Sunday nor Wednesday. Tomorrow is not Sunday or Wednesday.*

> Given our options, both sentences can't be true. So one of them is false and the last two are true.

*Yesterday was not Friday*

> Since this is true, it eliminates Saturday.

*Monday was not the day before yesterday, neither was Sunday.*

> Since this is true, it eliminates Wednesday and Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

Today is

> Sunday

Today is neither Sunday nor Wednesday.

> Assume this is false, and today is either Sunday or Wednesday

Tomorrow is not Sunday or Wednesday.

> This would be true for either, if it was Sunday, tomorrow is Monday, and if it was Wednesday, tomorrow is Thursday.

Yesterday was not Friday.

> This is also true assuming either Sunday or Wednesday

Monday was not the day before yesterday, neither was Sunday.

> This is false when assuming it is Wednesday. The day before yesterday would be Monday. That means there are two false statements, eliminating Wednesday, and leaving Sunday.

> When going through each of the remaining choices for the days, it is found that more than one statement is false, leaving Sunday to be the final answer.